# How to fire a "Complete" event from ViewModel?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a entry with complete action:

```
 <local:BaseEntry Placeholder="Email Address" Keyboard="Email"     x:Name="EmailEntry" ReturnType="Next" Completed="{Binding GoToPassword}"/>
```

I want to focus to the next entry when user press done button from keyboard.
So how to perform Completed action from ViewModel?

Comment: Do you solve this problem,if other problems you can show them.If solved ,thanks for marking answer in advance :)

Comment: Glad be helpful. *.^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how to perform Completed action from ViewModel?

Using `ReturnCommand` and `ReturnType` instead of `Completed` in Xaml:

```
<local:BaseEntry Placeholder="Email Address" Keyboard="Email" x:Name="EmailEntry" ReturnType="Next" ReturnCommand="{Binding CommandComplete}" ReturnType="Done"/>
```

Then in **ViewModel** add `CommandComplete` property:

```
 public System.Windows.Input.ICommand CommandComplete { get; set; }

 CommandComplete = new Command(() => { Console.WriteLine("Complete method"); });
```